# jquery remove() problem

Tags: jquery

See [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/y5gbg/)!!!
http://jsfiddle.net/y5gbg/
When I type something, it should append a round div and text. When I click this round div, it should be removed.
This is jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("button").click(function(){
     var str;
     str = $('input').val();
     var sth;
     sth = '<div id="'+str+'"><div class="btn" alt="'+str+'"></div><p>'+str+'</p><hr></div>';
     $("#contents").append(sth);
    });

    $('.btn').click(function(){
      var id;
      id = $(this).attr('alt');
      $('#'+id).remove();    
    });

});
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone tell me why?
Another thing, how to do linebreak here?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to use the live function

```
$('.btn').live('click', function(){
  var id;
  id = $(this).attr('alt');
  $('#'+id).remove();    
});
```

because you're adding the div to the dom dynamically so the click isn't getting registered to the div

[Here's an example of it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/josephbulger/32Fxp/)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the button removed then your code would be:

```
$('.btn').live("click", function(){
   $(this).remove();    
});
```

instead of what you currently have for `$('.btn')...`

Answer (score 0):

you can try `$('#'+id).hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `live()`

Here is your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/y5gbg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the live function for the second function

```
$('.btn').live('click',function(){
  var id;
  id = $(this).attr('alt');
  $('#'+id).remove();    
});
```